# Python Tkinter checkbuttons in MacOS - problem turning off the checkbutton indicator and displaying image with text

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI with image-based checkbuttons (like on-off switches) in Tkinter.
To do this, I'm creating giving the widget separate off and on images (image= and selectimage=) and setting indicatoron=tk.FALSE to remove the original check and box graphics.

This works until I try to also add text to the widget by setting compound=tk.LEFT (or other values).  When I do that, Tkinter gives the text a strange lighter background that changes depending on whether the window is in focus and whether I'm pressing the button - I can't figure out how to get rid of that effect.  It renders the text nearly unreadable.

See the attached screen shot:  [Screen shot of checkbuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuTvr.jpg)

I'm on a Mac and I know that tkinter does some strange things to comply with Mac UI standards.
The problem seems to be using indicatoron=tk.FALSE and compound=anything in the same widget.

Should this work, and am I doing something wrong?  I'm on MacOS Monterey and Python 3.11.

Below is a stand-alone example showing several different types of buttons with combinations of images, text, and indicatoron values.  The same thing happens with radiobutton (which, I think, is the only other widget with the indicatoron setting.

If I can't make this work, then I'll have to resort to making my buttons by hand out of Tkinter canvases.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk


class CheckbuttonCompoundIssue(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        im = Image.new('RGB', (30, 20), (0, 0, 0))  # make a green oval on a black background
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        draw.ellipse((3, 3, 27, 17), fill=(128, 255, 128))
        self.photo_image_on = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        draw.ellipse((3, 3, 27, 17), fill=(255, 128, 128))  # make the oval green for the off image
        self.photo_image_off = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

        tk.Label(text='CheckButtons').pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        tk.Checkbutton(self, image=self.photo_image_off, selectimage=self.photo_image_on,
                       indicatoron=tk.FALSE).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        tk.Checkbutton(self, text='no indicator& yes image',
                       image=self.photo_image_off, selectimage=self.photo_image_on,
                       compound=tk.LEFT, indicatoron=tk.FALSE).pack(padx=10, pady=10)  # changes text background

        tk.Checkbutton(self, text='yes indicator & yes image',
                       image=self.photo_image_off, selectimage=self.photo_image_on,
                       compound=tk.RIGHT, indicatoron=tk.TRUE).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        tk.Checkbutton(self, text='no indicator & no image',
                       indicatoron=tk.FALSE).pack(padx=10, pady=10)  # changes text background

        tk.Label(text='RadioButtons have the same problem').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text='Radio no indicator with image',
                       image=self.photo_image_off, selectimage=self.photo_image_on,
                       compound=tk.LEFT, indicatoron=tk.FALSE).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        tk.Radiobutton(self, text='Radio indicator with image',
                       image=self.photo_image_off, selectimage=self.photo_image_on,
                       compound=tk.LEFT, indicatoron=tk.TRUE).pack(padx=10, pady=10)


def main():
    app = CheckbuttonCompoundIssue()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```